# How to export a Jupyter Notebook as HTML to Windows file directory?

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory, nbconvert

I am trying to export a Jupyter Notebook (from Google Drive) as HTML to a specific directory on Windows (named  C:\outputfolder) with the following Python Code in Google Colab, which unfortunately doesn't work. The problem is about the command --output-dir=\C:\outputfolder\

```
Input:
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('./mount')
!jupyter nbconvert --to html 'mount/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Notebook1.ipynb' --output-dir=\C:\outputfolder\

Output:
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook mount/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Notebook1.ipynb to html
[NbConvertApp] Writing 574592 bytes to C:outputfolder\/Notebook1.html
```

Python doesn't save the HTML. Apparently the slashes are not correct. (missing slash between C: and outputfolder as well as contradictory slashes / later)

I tried it also with double backslashes to fix the slash problem, but without success as the final one remains like this "/".

```
Alternated Input:       
!jupyter nbconvert --to html 'mount/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Notebook1.ipynb' --output-dir=\\C:\\outputfolder\\

Output:
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook mount/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Notebook1.ipynb to html
[NbConvertApp] Writing 574592 bytes to \C:\outputfolder\/Notebook1.html
```

It is essential for me to export it directly to Windows file system, NOT along with the origin file in Google Drive!

I would really appreciate your help! :-)